# PostgreSQL - Made update to table in a function I created and now the order of rows in the table has changed

Tags: postgresql

Does anyone know why the order of the rows changed after I made an update to table? Is there any way to make the order go back or change to another order eg:order by alphabetical?

This is the update I performed:

```
update t set amount = amount + 1 where account = accountNumber
```

After this update when I go and see the table, the order has changed

Comment: Most RDBMS have no internal "order."  Of course, you can order your result set using any column you wish.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen how do I reorder using any column I wish?

Comment: Post your query (at least), and your table schema (even better).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen edited the post to include the query that messed up the order. This update is in a function.

Comment: No I think you are still confused.  You should not be concerned about what an `UPDATE` will do to the internal order.

Comment: What do you mean? Because after performing the update and I go to the database and type "select * from t;" the order is diffrent from what it used to be before the update.

Comment: This is what I am telling you.  You need to use `ORDER BY`

Comment: Oh my, I understand now. So there is no way to preset it to always show it in a particular order?

Comment: There is a way.  Use `ORDER BY`.  See the answer given below.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thank you for you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A table doesn't have a natural row order, some database systems will actually refuse your query if you don't add an `ORDER BY` clause at the end of your `SELECT`

*Why did the order change?*

Because the database engine fetches your rows in the physical order they come from the storage. Some engines, like SQL Server, can have a `CLUSTERED INDEX` which forces a physical order, but it is still never really guaranteed that you get your results in that precise order.

The clustered index exist mostly as an optimization. PostgreSQL has a similar `CLUSTER` function to change the physical order, but it's an heavy process which locks the table : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-cluster.html

*How to force an alphabetical order of the rows?*

Add an `ORDER BY` clause in your query.

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column
```

Comment: Thanks I understand now!